# How to find dependencies on Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, flask

I have a personal AWS account for tooling around, I currently mainly use it to host a python flask app.  In the past I've done various tutorials through AWS Popup loft and other things, so there's some random detritus still around.

In my monthly bill from AWS though, the majority of the charges are for AWS Elasticsearch.  From what I'm reading, it doesn't sound like I need this for anything in particular.  I suspect it's a leftover from a tutorial session on a set of features I don't use anymore.

My immediate question is: will shutting down my AWS Elasticsearch domain brick my flask app?

My general question is: how can I find out what is using my AWS Elasticsearch domain, or at least when it was set up?

Comment: How about looking what kind of indices you have? That might be helpful and you might ring some bells.

Comment: Indices on what?

Comment: I'm talking about the indexes you have in your ES.